# How do i connect to the Live database(Mysql) using Mysql command prompt?

Tags: mysql

> I have tried the following command syntax to connect with live
>   database...

```
-u Username -pPassword -h HostName Database Name
```

> But there is an error
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ' -u Username -pPassword -h HostName Database Name'

Comment: At least in your example in every second parameter you have a space between parameter letter and parameter.

Comment: Did you try omitting the database name. You can always use "show databases" and "use databases"

Comment: You are not supposed to type these commands to the MySQL client, you are supposed to supply them as arguments when launching MySQL client.

Comment: You've tagged this question with "php". Are you actually trying to execute those commands via PHP? Or are you typing them into something? If the latter, is it a shell you're typing into, or a MySQL client? Please provide a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks for replying all...
@Jaakkko Kaski: Yes its my mistake... there is an space in second parameter...
But still not getting connected..

---->Matt Gibson: i just want to connect to DB using Mysql Command prompt... nothing more than that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this... This might help you

[connect to mysql database using command line and php](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-connect-to-my-mysql-database-server-using-command-line-and-php/)

Answer (score 0):

The command you're describing is for connecting to the database in command line. If you need to connect to a database inside a PHP script, you must use:

- [`mysqli_connect` aka `mysqli::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)
- [`PDO::__construct`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

I'm not recommending it but if you're stuck with legacy code, `mysql_connect` also does the same for the deprecated mysql_* extension.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using this command already on mysql shell prompt or on phpmyadmin like sql frontend. You must not use this command on mysql-shell as you are already loggin into mysql. Try this command on bash shell on linux or dos prompt on windows.

```
mysql -u Username -pPassword -h HostName DatabaseName
```

One more thing, If you are using windows (like wamp/xampp). You may need to pass full mysql path like

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql -u Username -pPassword -h HostName DatabaseName
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @kuldeep.kamboj
Still getting the same error....
am typing the IP address of my website at the "HostName"...
Is am doing write?

Comment: Did you try this command on dos prompt or any application like phpmyadmin

Comment: Is there any other way that you know...
i have only UserName, Password, HostName(IpAddress) and Database Name